# How to solve this wrong ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait is Deprecated in IOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am updating app in IOS 8, ADBanner shows this wrong, how to solve this issue. 'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait'is deprecated:first deprecated in iOS 6.0 and 'requiredContentSizeIdentifiers' is deprecated :first deprecated in iOS 6.0.
This is my Code, please check this one.

```
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

Comment: currentContentSizeIdentifer is deprecated:first deprecated in iOS 6.0 .this wrong is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the lines with:

```
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```